# c# increase 2 number untill max value

Tags: c#

So I have 2 `numbers`:

```
4 bit - Allowed range is 0-15
12 bit - Allowed range is 0-4095
```

And I want to create `function` that get 2 `numbers` and increase this 2 `numbers`, first the 12 `bit` number and after this number reach its max - set it to zero and increase the second `number`.

For example:

```
for 1 and 2 - 1, 3
for 1 and 4094 - 1, 4095
for 1 and 4095 - 2, 0
for 15 and 4095 - 0, 0
```

This is my solution:

```
public static Tuple<int, int> IncreaseSequenceControl(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
{
    if (firstNumber < 15)
    {
        if (secondNumber < 4095)
        {
            secondNumber += 1;
            return Tuple.Create<int, int>(firstNumber, secondNumber);
        }
        else
        {
             firstNumber += 1;
             secondNumber = 0;
             return Tuple.Create<int, int>(firstNumber, secondNumber);
         }
    }
    else
    {
         firstNumber = 0;
         return Tuple.Create<int, int>(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    }
}
```

Any other or maybe more elegant solution or this is fine ?

Comment: Consider the first 4 bits as high, and the remaining 12 as low, then this is identical to simply increasing a 16-bit unsigned integer and reading off the bit ranges as separate numbers.

Comment: Can I have code example?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a (useless) coding contest question... I suggest you read about bit operators (mainly `|`, `&` for this specific task), bit-shift operators (like `<<` and `>>`) and bit masks (like `0x0fff`).

Comment: If we may assume the numbers are in range: `ushort s = (ushort) unchecked(((firstNumber << 12) | secondNumber) + 1); return (s >> 12, s & 0xFFF);`. It is probable the first two numbers are themselves derived from a 16-bit quantity; if so the whole converting to and from business is of course unnecessary and you could just directly increment a `ushort`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in multiple ways, Here is a one-liner:

```
public static (int, int) IncreaseSequenceControl(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) => (
     (firstNumber + Math.DivRem(secondNumber + 1, 4096, out int remainder)) 
         is <= 15 and var result 
         ? result 
         : 0, 
     remainder
);
```

To make this clearer, I'll write a more readable version of the above solution:

```
// First number is the 4 bit number
// Second number is the 12 bit number
public static (int, int) IncreaseSequenceControl(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
{
    int quotient = Math.DivRem(secondNumber + 1, 4096, out int remainder);
    // The quotient represents how many times the 4095 limit has been hit.
    // If the quotient is 0, the secondNumber is less than 4096.
    // The remainder will contain the value left after incrementing the firstNumber as many times as the value of the quotient, so remainder can be assigned to second number

    // Increment firstNumber as many times as the 4096 limit was hit
    int result = firstNumber + quotient;
    if (result <= 15)
    {
         firstNumber = result;
    }
    else
    {
        // If result is greater than 15, set to 0
        firstNumber = 0;
    }
    // The leftover value after the quotient
    secondNumber = remainder;
    return (firstNumber, secondNumber);
}
```

The `Math.DivRem()` function takes in a dividend and divisor and returns the quotient. The function also takes in an `out` parameter through which the remainder will be returned.

Also you might have noticed that I have `(int, int)` as the return type. It is a short-hand way / syntax sugar for `System.ValueTuple<int, int>`.  Using `ValueTuple` is recommended over using `Tuple`. Firstly, because they offer this syntax sugar. Secondly, implementing tuple as a reference type through the `Tuple` class is considered a "mistake" which was fixed with `ValueTuple`.

Comment: 1, 2 become 2, 3, this is wrong, first i need to increase the last number (the 12 bit one) and only after its reach the max value (4095) increase the 4 bit number.

Comment: @user1860934 It was because I was adding to `firstNumber` twice in the longer version. Just fixed it, try now. Also, the one-line version was already correct.

Comment: @user1860934 Did this solve your problem?